# What I need to change in request to be able to access the new Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I'm using the default rules for firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

But now I want to permit only logged users to manipulate the data in Firebase, so I found this rule on Internet:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I have to change in my code to be able to access the db with the logged users? Is there a way to do it globally or I need to change every get in the code? Above is an example of query I have:

```dart
await databaseReference
        .collection("col1").doc('myDocs').collection(colThings)
        .orderBy('day')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((f) => things.add(f.data()));
    })
```

And another question about it: This rule, once running properly, covers all firebase or only Firestore?

Comment: Do you mean all authenticated users can access the whole database or allow users to access access their own data?

Comment: all authenticated

Comment: all authenticated

Comment: all authenticated

Comment: all authenticated

Comment: Hello @armstrong, slr. I usually do that way, using firestore rules and firebase authentication into my login module to allow only authenticated user and access my module that contain get, create and delete function. I can't give you right now my sample due to my Android Studio problem.